# Range Definition for Autofilter in VBA Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I was wondering, what the correct way was to define a Range for an Autofilter.
When recording a Macro it comes back with:

`Range("$A$4:$AS$600").AutoFilter Field:=1 Criteria1:= "Apples"`

however, if I write the code myself as:

`Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=1 Criteria1:= "Apples"`

the result is the same.

why not just use  `Range("A4")` all the time?

Answer (score 0):

The version you are entering is also the one suggested by help page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter

Specifying the whole range matters while no filters were applied before (no drop down arrows in header cells), so information on whole range is required.

Comment: so if there was no Filter set in the file originally, I would have to use the ```Range("$A$4:$AS$600").Autofilter``` for it to work, and if there are already filters present ```Range("A4").autofilter``` Is sufficient?